# Assigning value to interface property

Tags: c#, .net

I've defined an interface like this:

```
public interface myInterface {
  int SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

In the inheriting class, I've done this:

```
public class MyClass:myInterface {
  public int SomeProperty = 5;
}
```

But then I get this error:

```
MyClass does not implement interface member myInterface.SomeProperty.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: cos I misread something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared `SomeProperty` as a [field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), not a [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). You should do it like this:

```
public class MyClass:myInterface
{
  public MyClass()
  {
     SomeProperty = 5;
  }

  public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Or, if you're using C# 6, you can shorten it to this:

```
public class MyClass:myInterface
{
  public int SomeProperty { get; set; } = 5;
}
```

Comment: so a get/set on an interface creates a field? IN a class it creates an automatically backed property

Comment: @pm100, that's not what I said. An interface cannot have fields. `{ get; set; }` is always a property, whether it's in a class or in an interface.

Comment: ah yes, i read it upside down